# Put two columns in one column in sequence one under another - Google Sheets / Excel

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to simplify my life guys, help me. I want to, when I have two columns that I need the information of those two columns in just one - Not concatenated, the columns placed one under another - and everytime that one of those two columns be delected or added, the column that have the informations of those two columns update. :)

> If we could make a function in appscript to do it would be amazing, or whether there's a way to do it with the stardard functions that google sheets provide, it would be much better yet.

Follow the pic to be able to imagine what I am speaking of (I am brazilian and my english is not that good):

[image]

Thank you guys, you are amazing!

Comment: Google Sheets and Excel are not the same. If you truly don't care which you receive a solution for, then you can leave the tags the same ... otherwise, probably best to be specific which of the two you *actually* want.

Answer (score 3):

Using built-in function (google sheet) you could try

```
=filter({A2:A; B2:B}; len({A2:A; B2:B}))
```

or, depending on your locale

```
=filter({A2:A; B2:B}, len({A2:A; B2:B}))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function col1col2() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const col1 = sh.getRange(2,1,getColumnHeight(1,sh,ss)-1).getValues().flat();
  const col2 = sh.getRange(2,2,getColumnHeight(2,sh,ss)-1).getValues().flat();
  const col3 = col1.concat(col2).map(e => [e]);
  sh.getRange(2,3,col3.length,1).setValues(col3);
}
```

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 0 | 8 |
| 18 | 9 | 18 |
| 1 | 17 | 1 |
| 2 | 5 | 2 |
|  |  | 0 |
|  |  | 9 |
|  |  | 17 |
|  |  | 5 |

```
function getColumnHeight(col, sh, ss) {
  var ss = ss || SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = sh || ss.getActiveSheet();
  var col = col || sh.getActiveCell().getColumn();
  var rcA = [];
  if (sh.getLastRow()){ rcA = sh.getRange(1, col, sh.getLastRow(), 1).getValues().flat().reverse(); }
  let s = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < rcA.length; i++) {
    if (rcA[i].toString().length == 0) {
      s++;
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }
  return rcA.length - s;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it using `QUERY`.

If your columns are `A` and `B` then use the following formula in `C2`:

`=QUERY({A2:A;B2:B}, "select Col1 where Col1 is not null", 1)`

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Another similar solution would be to use something like this:

`=filter({A2:A;B2:B}, {A2:A;B2:B}<>"")`

This does the same exact thing as `=filter({A2:A; B2:B}, len({A2:A; B2:B}))` (as provided in another answer), but just filters out any blank cells, instead of filtering by length. It's simply another way to look at it.